# Are instance methods copied for each new instance?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I'm currently choosing between factory pattern vs constructor. If the CLR does indeed copy them, then using constructors would probably be waste of resources since the class in this case is instantiated alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "copy instance constructors" you are asking whether *code* for these methods is generated per-instance, the answer is no. All instances of a type share the same code for their methods, properties and constructors.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question. Maybe you got a reference from the top of your head?

Comment: If that answers the question then be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: See this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) entry on Object-Oriented programming: "When a method is invoked on an object, the object itself determines what code gets executed by looking up the method at run time in a table associated with the object. This feature distinguishes an object from an abstract data type (or module), which has a fixed (static) implementation of the operations for all instances. It is a programming methodology that gives modular component development while at the same time being very efficient."